# XAdES signature using Google Cloud KMS

Tags: java, digital-signature, google-cloud-kms, xades

Is there any way to make XAdES signature using Google Cloud KMS? I cannot find any info about it.

Comment: Here's the supported keys and algorithms: https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Wow, XAdES is a maze of twisty standards documents, it's tough to find what is supported. From what I can tell, [XMLDSIG](https://www.w3.org/TR/2002/REC-xmldsig-core-20020212/#sec-AlgID) originally supported DSA and RSA-SHA1 which are now pretty dated and neither is supported by Cloud KMS's [algorithms](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/algorithms#asymmetric_signing_algorithms).

In 2013 [XML Signature Syntax and Processing Version 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmldsig-core1/#sec-Algorithms) which specified some more algorithms, including an RSA algorithm with SHA-256 which should be compatible with Cloud KMS's `RSA_SIGN_PKCS1_2048_SHA256`, `RSA_SIGN_PKCS1_3072_SHA256` and `RSA_SIGN_PKCS1_4096_SHA256`. and I believe its `ECDSAwithSHA384` should be compatible with Cloud KMS's `EC_SIGN_P384_SHA384`.

There may have been further developments since then with other supported algorithms. I suspect that particular XAdES implementations or interoperability groups may only support a selection of algorithms, so you may need to check with those for interoperable algorithms.

All that said, Cloud KMS does not provide the tooling to encode the documents for signing nor encode the signatures in a way compatible with XAdES, so while I believe, if you had algorithmic compatibility, you could implement signing with keys stored in Cloud KMS, but it would take a chunk of work to do the various format conversions.

Thanks for using GCP and Cloud KMS. If you have more info on what you wish it could do, I'd be happy to get the request.